# Visited badge link color on mobile

Tags: bug, design

As you can see in the images, the visited link has a dark blue color and the background is black. It's not readable.

[image: badge info]
[image: badge list]

Comment: This is the same behaviour for all sites of SE. I have flaged this to be migrated to meta.SE

Comment: @Heslacher I have not been able to see this behavior on other SE sites. As such, I declined your flag. I think this is related to our design.

Comment: @SimonForsbergMcFeely I could at least reproduce this on [SO].

Comment: Duplicate of [Badges are sometimes unreadable in mobile theme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258737/badges-are-sometimes-unreadable-in-mobile-theme) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @200_success Oh, sorry, I didn't test on mobile. Missed that part.

Comment: The mobile design is common to all sites, and I can see this behaviour on multiple sites.